# Median on weekdays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to determine the median of a set of data for each weekday. Currently, the data is in two columns, date and value. Some of the value rows are blank, as the data to be analyzed hasn't be entered yet. I've had a look at the median-if array formula, but when I combine it with Weekday function I just get an error

> {=Median(if(Weekday('Data'!A:A)=1, 'Data'!B:B)}

This is the current formula I'm working with to calculate the median value for Sundays, and all I get out of it #VALUE!.

Comment: Rather than use a whole column reference, you should just use the range you want to evaluate for the calculation.  If you have something other than a date in Column A, it will throw the #Value error.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying a Comment from [@sous2817](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652301/sous2817):

> Rather than use a whole column reference, you should just use the range you want to evaluate for the calculation. If you have something other than a date in Column A, it will throw the #Value error.